# VLC Media Player opening subtitle from the same folder as movie

Tags: vlc-media-player, subtitles, file-location

Until the last upgrade of VLC, when I tried to open a subtitle for a movie, after choosing the "open subtitle" in the menu, a window opened showing the same folder where the movie file was located. (I usually start the movie file in Total Commander, not in VLC and I want to do so in the future too).
After the last upgrade, when I try to add a subtitle to a movie, it starts a window showing the last in the VLC opened folder (the folder of the subtitle of the last viewed movie or folder of last listened music.)
Where and how can I set, that at opening a subtitle the VLC opens automatically the folder of the movie just being watched?
I use Windows 10 Home 64 bit version and VLC Media Player 3.0.3 version

Comment: There is not setting that I can find, and you are correct, they have broken that function, hopefully it will get fixed in the next version of VLC.

Answer (score 0):

This was discussed in the [VLC forums](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=144733&p=474766&hilit=folder#p473786), and the following answer was given:

> This is fixed for 3.0.4. Please try a nightly build, if you want.

If you're interesting in trying a nightly build, they can be found [here](https://nightlies.videolan.org/).

---

I also noticed that a workaround is mentioned:

> I have found out that I can drag and drop my subtitles from the folder I am presently in directly into the window.